# ES6 Export Overwriting Function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I export this overwriting function so that an importing module can check whether the function has been called?

```
// util.js
export function isPageload() {
  return (!!(isPageload = function() { return false; }));
}
```

When I compile that with Babel, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _util2.default) is not a function
```

Here is the ES5 equivalent:

```
var isPageload = function() {
  return (!!(isPageload = function() { return false; }));
}

console.log(isPageload()); // true
console.log(isPageload()); // false
```

Comment: `let loaded = false;` then `loaded = true;` in the function body.

Comment: more pertinently, why would you write this? Why do you need the same function name in your export?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The current syntax would update the export to be a function that returns false instead of the original function, just like the ES5 version.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `.default` in the error makes it clear that you are doing

```
import isPageload from 'foo';
```

when you probably want

```
import {isPageload} from 'foo';
```

since

```
export function isPageload() {
```

creates a named export, not a default export, and default export live-binding updating [currently does not work in Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2228).

Your approach to this problem does seem somewhat roundabout however. Why not do

```
let loaded = true;
export isPageLoaded(){
    let state = loaded;
    loaded = false;
    return loaded;
}
```