# Webpack for Angular2 will not find my jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular, webpack

I am using Webpack. How do I import jQuery into Angular2?

I added to package.json

```
"jquery": "^3.1.0",
```

Added this to index.html

```
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Will not find

http://localhost:3000/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js

I even tried the below:

```
<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Yes, jQuery is in node_modules.

Comment: you need for `import $ from "jquery"`, webpack will bundle that for you. Don't use script tags.

Comment: And also this might be interesting for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39424340/include-jquery-in-angular2-with-webpack-and-access-it-from-component

Comment: this is what  i get:L  Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: jquery_1.default is not a function

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793404/es6-export-overwriting-function

Answer (score 0):

You have to either

```
import * as $ from "jquery"
// or import * as jQuery from "jquery"
// or import * as jquery from "jquery"
// depending on what identifier you want to use for jQuery function
```

in every file, you use jquery, or edit your `webpack.config` to recognize jQuery, for example:

```
plugins: [
...
     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery'
    }),
...
]
```

and of course, remove `<script>` tags you added from index.html

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this:

```
npm install expose-loader
```

inside vendor.ts:

```
import 'expose?jQuery!../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js';
```

inside your app .ts files. first declare a var named jQuery to get a ref to jQuery.

```
declare var jQuery: any;
jQuery('#...') ...
```